# Django having problem in adding user to specific group

Tags: python, django

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username','email','password1','password2')

def save(self,commit=True):
    user = super(UserForm,self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password = self.cleaned_data['password1']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    
    if commit:
        user.save()
```

**views.py**

```
def register_view(request):
    form = UserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()

            customer_group = Group.objects.filter(name='CUSTOMER').exists()
            if customer_group:
                Group.objects.get(name='CUSTOMER').user_set.add(user)
            else:
                Group.objects.create(name='CUSTOMER')
                Group.objects.get(name='CUSTOMER').user_set.add(user)
          
            messages.success(request,'註冊成功! 請按指示登入!')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'註冊無效! 請再試過!')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'customer/register.html',context)
```

When I try to register a new user, the form can be successfully saved and the group `CUSTOMER` can be added but I have a problem if I want to add that user to the group so are there any methods in order to add the user to the group automatically after that user had registered a new account along with the `User` model?

Comment: Your `UserForm` has indentation issues but not returning the created user from the save method may be your issue

Comment: So what is the problem in the save method?

Comment: No `return user` line at the end of the method?

Comment: So I should add ```return user``` at the save method right?

Comment: Yes you should.

Comment: Actually you should not override the `save()` in the first place: you already inherit from the `UserCreationForm`, so that is implemented properly.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Iain Shelvington says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71290234/django-having-problem-in-adding-user-to-specific-group#comment126013281_71290234), the `form.save()` method should return the user object. But there is no need to override the `save()` method: the `UserCreationForm` already does that.

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email')

    # no save method
```

In the view you can simplify the logic to:

```
def register_view(request):
    form = UserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            customer_group, __ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='CUSTOMER')
            customer_group.user_set.add(user)
          
            messages.success(request,'註冊成功! 請按指示登入!')
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'註冊無效! 請再試過!')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'customer/register.html',context)
```